# Convert Join and Group By from SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, linq

I'm new with LINQ and I need help Converting this SQL Code: To LINQ

```
    SELECT UserId_FK,COUNT(OrderId),SUM(Quantity)
    FROM Orders o
    JOIN OrderDetails od
    ON(o.OrderId = od.OrderId_FK)
    GROUP BY UserId_FK;
```

Comment: This is a good resource for linq questions. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Take a look at [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) it converts SQL to LINQ (amongst other things).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your schema file, I'm going to take a guess here:

```
var userDetail =
    context.Orders
        .GroupBy(i => i.UserId_Fk)
        .Select(i => new {
                         UserId_Fk = i.Key,
                         OrderCount = i.Count(),
                         ProductQuantity = i.Sum(j => context.OrderDetails.Where(k=> k.OrderId_Fk == j.OrderId).Sum(k=> k.Quantity))
                      });
```

Comment: Ahh I was just about to post you beat me to it.

Comment: Thx guys im going to try it out